# Magento2 2.0.0-rc custom module error?

Tags: magento2

today i install Magento2 2.0.0-rc and setup my module confign but get error

```
Setup version for module 'Test_Newconfign' is not specified.
```

this code file module in **Test/Newconfign/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Newconfign" setup_version="2.0.0" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create registration.php file in root of module with content

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Newconfign',
    __DIR__
);
```

and in composer.json add to autoload section `"files": [ "registration.php" ],`

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Test\\Newconfign\\": ""
    }
}
```

Than reinstall your module/magento (`composer install` is required)

Also "../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd" should be changed to "urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd"

Comment: i edited same but not success

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: when i  run code get error The following modules are outdated:
Test_Newconfign schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Test_Newconfign data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0

Comment: run bin/magento setup:upgrade